# React Native Android Build with new architecture enabled taking too long

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, azure-pipelines, react-native-turbomodule

I have a react native project with newArchitecure enabled (i.e new NativeModule system (TurboModule) and the new Renderer (Fabric)). I tried to build this project in Azure DevOps pipeline using gradle build for generating android .apk.

But the Build is taking too long( i.e more than an hour, which auto-cancelled after 1 hour as longest build allowed was 1 hr in Azure DevOps settings. Hence it din't get completed).
Even when I try to build locally also it is taking too long to build with the new architecture. Where as if i disable the newArchitecure (flag in android/gradle.properties) the build completes around 20 mins.

My question was is this issue faced by anyone who is working with react native? and if yes is there any solution to increase build speed of react native android app in Azure DevOps pipeline?